# Getting "Invalid extension descriptor" compiling Flex Native Extensions

Tags: android, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I'm getting "Invalid extension descriptor" compiling a Flex Native Extension for Android. Everything in the extension.xml file seems to be ok.

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
    <id>com.samples.NESample</id>
    <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="Android-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>notification.jar</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>com.samples.NESample.NESampleExtension</initializer>
                <finalizer>com.samples.NESample.NESampleExtension</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
    </platforms>
</extension>
```

Please, help me tryto figure out what's wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that command prompt doesn't find the file "extension.xml".
Lets say you have your file in "C:\Users". Make sure in command prompt also you are in same directory .. c:\Users>

Answer (score 0):

That file looks fine, it might be how you are passing it to adt when you compile rather than the file itself?

I use something like this:

```
adt -package    -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 -storepass password \
                -target ane extensionname.ane extension.xml \
                -swc actionscript/bin/extensionname.swc \
                -platform Android-ARM -C android/bin .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out my cmd was in wrong directory. Navigate to the build folder and then run the adt command.